# Checking for continuity

Tags: continuity

I got following "two" functions:

$g(x) = 1 - |2x-1|$ with $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = g(x- \lfloor x \rfloor)$ with x$\in\mathbb{R}$, and I have to check whether f(x) is continuous or not.

The Problem here is that I don't quiet understand what the function f looks like? Is it $f(x) = 1 - |2(x -\lfloor x \rfloor) -1|$ ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case.

Comment: Here's a hint. The floor function is a piecewise defined function.